# Anchor tag doesn't link properly in webkit-based browsers only

Tags: jquery, html, webkit

I have an anchor tag that doesn't behave correctly in webkit-based browsers. I originally thought that it was because I have a regular expression to dynamically turn urls in a string of text to proper anchor tags. I removed all dynamic code and animations, and I still had the same issue. I also tried giving the element an enormous z-index, but that didn't work either. While playing with it, I noticed that the mouseover event is getting triggered, but the click event is not.

The URL is http://stream9.net. When you hover over the Twitter bird, our most recent tweet pulls out from the right and reveals the url at the end. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: where does the problem occur? what do i need to click on to see this in action? in other words, how do I reproduce the issue? if you can put some simplified sample code on http://www.jsfiddle.net it would be appreciated